# Testing/Mocking ReactComponent SVG imports with Jest

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs, enzyme, react-component

I am importing SVG's into my component and importing them as components using `ReactComponent`, for example

```js
import { ReactComponent as D1 } from '../../../assets/images/characteristics/D1.svg';
```

When I run Jest/Enzyme to test the component, I get the following error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Does it appear that I need to mock this? How could I do that?

Comment: so it's [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) who loads SVG as React component, am I right? If I'm accurate here, it's a webpack loader. Did you try mocking svg through `moduleNameMapper` as [their docs suggested](https://react-svgr.com/docs/jest/)?

Comment: Hi @skyboyer
I believe it does use SVGR under the hood as i use create-react-app.
Thanks, I will try this and report back

Comment: Hi @skyboyer,this works thanks

Comment: cool! could you please make a self-answer with bit of instructions? someone may find this by search and barely read comments, only looking for answers

Answer (score 10):

Although the solution pointed out by @skyboyer worked for me, it showed the following error in the console when running the tests:

```
<SvgrURL /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, 
or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

Changing to the following inside the mock file worked for me as a solution:

```
import React from 'react';
 
const SvgrMock = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <span ref={ref} {...props} />);

export const ReactComponent = SvgrMock;
export default SvgrMock;
```

[reference](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/83#issuecomment-575038115)

Comment: This is the perfect solution to mock svg files for @svgr/webpack 

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a mock file for svg and put it in the __mocks__ folder
2. Add a module name mapper inside jest config

**__mocks__/svgMock.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const SvgrMock = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <span ref={ref} {...props} />);
export const ReactComponent = SvgrMock;
export default SvgrMock;
```

**Jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    moduleNameMapper: {
        ...
        '\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgMock.js',
    },
};
```